# hide attributes in object oriented perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

Recently I am using chilkat perl library for sending email

http://www.example-code.com/perl/smtp_simpleSend.asp

when i create new object

```
use chilkat();

#  The mailman object is used for sending and receiving email.
$mailman = new chilkat::CkMailMan();
$mailman->put_SmtpHost("smtp.chilkatsoft.com");
#  Set the SMTP login/password (if required)
$mailman->put_SmtpUsername("myUsername");
$mailman->put_SmtpPassword("myPassword");
```

when i try to print the object using Dumper method it returns nothing.

```
print Dumper($mailMan);
$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'chilkat::CkMailMan' );
```

how can we hide the data in blessed object like above?

Comment: All in all, the code of this stuff looks not very modern. The examples do not even have strict, and neither does the pm file itself.

Comment: I wouldn't use any outside code that isn't on [CPAN](http://cpan.org). ( AFAIAC if it's not on CPAN, it doesn't exist. )

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the code. It loads a C library (dll on Windows) with DynaLoader. The rest is only constructors. The properties (like `SmptHost`) are not kept in the Perl datastructure. It is just passed on to C function calls. I'm not even sure you can have several distinct objects at the same time. That's why  there is nothing in the blessed hash.

---

You cannot just hide the data. There are no private methods in normal Perl objects. There is always a way to get to the stuff. There are object frameworks that make it harder to serialize it with Data::Dumper, but that is not the purpose of these. Take a look at [Class::Std::Fast::Storable](https://metacpan.org/module/Class%3a%3aStd%3a%3aFast%3a%3aStorable) for example.